# How I can select previous element in Selenium based of condition after?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a bellow HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div><span class="checkbox"></span></div>
  <a title="something"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div><span class="checkbox"></span></div>
  <a title="somethingelse"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to click on the checkbox if the a's title is something.  I do not know how many rows are there so I need to check every row and if there the title == 'something' click the previous checkbox.

I tried to implement this in Python and Selenium, but so far could not succeed.  I can check for a like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[contains(@class, 'row')]//a[@title='something']")
```

But how I can select the previous element?

Does anybody have a recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `get_attribute` and trying to extract `title` and then putting a if clause that if title attribute text matches with your expected string then click on the above check box.

try this :

```
actual_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[contains(@class, 'row')]//a[@title='something']")
if actual_text.get_attribute('title') == 'your expected string here':
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'row')]//a[@title='something']/../child::span")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='row']/a[@title='something']/..//span[@class='checkbox']").click()
```